# Cannot call off to Class Library from API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get my .NET Target Framework 5.0 WebApi project to make a call into a class library. The class library ("MyLib") will basically call off to the database and return a fully loaded object. In this case the object is called a Policy ("p") . Currently I get a "**The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.**" error where it refers to the DataAccess layer that is within my class library. What do I need to do to properly initialize the DB connection? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
public class WriteHeadersController : ControllerBase
{
    private SqlConnection _Cn = new SqlConnection("integrated security=SSPI;data source=XXXXX\\YYYY;Initial Catalog=MyDB");

    [HttpGet]
    public WcStatLine GetWriteHeader()
    {
        WcStatRpt wcs = new WcStatRpt();
        _Cn.Open();
        SqlTransaction transaction= _Cn.BeginTransaction(); 
        MyLib.Model.Policy_2.Policy p = new MyLib.Model.Policy_2.Policy();

        MyLib.BLL.Policy_2.Policy bllpol = new MyLib.BLL.Policy_2.Policy();

        // It errors out here at the load
        p = bllpol.Load(4001996);

        WcStatLine line = new WcStatLine(ld, r);
        return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?  What is the stack trace for the exception?  I don't see how the `SqlConnection` shown is in any way related to the operation(s) from `MyLib`.  (Or why the `SqlConnection` shown is even needed...)

Comment: do you have a `ConnectionStrings` in your `appsettings.json` in your Api project?

Comment: The connection string is normally in the configuration file.

Comment: I do have it in my app settings as well. I guess I would need to know how to refer to it. To David's point I am wondering if I would need a using transaction statement or something. How does the policy load in the MyLib know to use the connection string I am trying to provide.

Comment: It would be better to show your code inside your library, and how you initialized the connection string there. I don't see you set `_Cn` in your `bllpol`.

Comment: Could you provide the codes which could reproduce the error?It's hard to figout what's wrong with the codes you've shown